# how to change fcurve for material value

Tags: shader-nodes

So i made these funky cool material ;) with a custom node group and an input value, which i like to animate. Works. But...

I cannot see in any animation-change editor the fcurve so i cannot change it which i would like to do. Is this possible? if yes, how?

[image]

Comment: Click on the group node so it's active. The fcurve should show up in the graph editor. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Can't reproduce. (Yet.) Are both the object and node-group active, when you attempt to see/modifiy the f-curve?

Comment: thank you both!!!! i am too silly. My object was hidden, so i did not select it. works!!!